# Evenly distribute a given number of segments along an existing path

Tags: paperjs

without seeing the codepen it is tricky to explain my situation, but here goes. I'm creating some paths by getting pathData using opentype.js. I am then placing random shapes at the position of the path's segment's points. Because of the nature of a font's paths some paths have far more segments than others for example '1' has way fewer segments thant '0'. I would like to average out the number of segments along each path so that when I add the shapes they look a consistent number of segments. Thanks in advance.

Is it possible to evenly distribute a given number of segments along an existing path?

[Here is a link to the Codepen](https://codepen.io/limitedunlimited/pen/vYeOLVv)

```
paper.install(window);
const minMax = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
};
window.onload = () => {
  paper.setup("canvas");
  let pathData;
  const font = opentype.load(
    "https://assets.codepen.io/1070/pphatton-ultralight-webfont.woff",
    (err, font) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        class Doughnut {
          constructor(x, y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.shape = new paper.Path.RegularPolygon({
              position: [this.x, this.y],
              sides: minMax(3, 8),
              radius: minMax(6, 12),
              fillColor: "black"
            });
          }
          // makeShape(){
          //   this.shape
          // }
        }
        pathData = font.getPath("100", 0, 600, 600).toSVG();
        // const rect = new paper.Path.Rectangle({
        //   point: [80, 25],
        //   size: [300, 200],
        //   fillColor: "black"
        // });
        const number = new paper.Path(pathData);
        number.selected = true;
        // number.flatten(10);
        const amount = 50;
        const length = number.length
        const points = [];

        const segments = number.segments;
        number.fitBounds(paper.view.bounds);
        for(let i = 0; i < amount; i++){
          const offset = i / amount * length
          const point = number.getPointAt(offset)
                    new Doughnut(point.x, point.y);

        }
        segments.forEach((seg) => {
          points.push(number.getPointAt(seg));
        });


        points.forEach((point) => {
          console.log(point);
          new Doughnut(point.x, point.y);
        });
        number.reduce();
      }
    }
  );

  const shapes = [];
  class Doughnut {
    constructor(x, y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.shape = new paper.Path.RegularPolygon({
        position: [this.x, this.y],
        sides: minMax(3, 8),
        radius: minMax(6, 12),
        fillColor: "black"
      });
    }
    // makeShape(){
    //   this.shape
    // }
  }

  // for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  //   shapes.push(new Doughnut(minMax(100, 500), minMax(100, 500)));
  // }
  // console.log(shapes)
  // shapes.makeShape()
};
```

[image: Image show the number 100 the '1' has long path sections without segments whereas the '0's' have even number of segments]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [path.divideAt()](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#divideat-location) method can help you greatly.
What is tricky in your case is that, in order to preserve the path appearance, you can't move the existing segments. So you'll have to find a way to only add segment where it is needed.
Otherwise, here's a simple [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.15/S/fVRda9swFP0rwi+Vl+C5hbLiNIMs7G2DsT6mfVCl61itIwVJSRjB/31XUvy5LgZjdO45OrpHks+JYjtIiuTpHRyvknnCtfBjrpV1hEvDayBLouBEfjFXZeuA0POzeVYEHw7KgSnIJp+T/GXewoYJebAF+XLfQRZq4A5EQZw5gEebdOE//o12BglMbceOv1uwNy2N3v1j6TRCdzmCt/kAvmrbGWZ7baWTWqFzbLpHZmRzgV71QQmbnaRwFcK9eljwi5r0xWutYKXESogn2O4wMos+VDrYpWT5lfRp9nQk+HoWBjTNnGHK1swBxQ6xzdhEL6pBbXFVy6jO4nDCsQ72yLjLJzgaGeZ79cv66UMva60Nvcz5OQh7w1IbgjXUIf12gZ/H5WAOBGaztG+q99FlaVGGZPIpzLkYccLChTxKAStHI7l3bbqzBe5gVKSHajONO+zW+pLiB+HTyIhzT47eNVlHmh5cW+nT9Z0Ne2kvlAwT/M54RemZ7LVUjjSB/d9bNrxpQTAfVtrLdj9CS1nXa11rlNxoPDxbuOmiTNOQW9vEcPmjbEaFSfcfiEJ215QDgn/3Rr9hKWPcySP8YH/AZKV038JtokcJp/ZmWc4wjzx7SKMaf1SvBth7CMMmxeal+Qs=) demonstrating a possible solution. It should get you on the track to find a solution more specific to your use case.

```js
const circle = new Path.Circle({
    center: [0, 0],
    radius: 75,
    selected: true
});

const rectangle = new Path.Rectangle({
    from: [0, 0],
    to: [200, 100],
    selected: true
});

rectangle.position = circle.position + [circle.bounds.width + rectangle.bounds.width, 0];

const cloneAndAddSegments = (item) => {
    const clone = item.clone().translate(0, 200);
    const length = clone.length;
    const step = 20;
    const iterations = Math.floor(length / step);
    for (let i = 1; i <= iterations; i++) {
        const offset = i * step;
        clone.divideAt(offset);
    }
    return clone;
};

const circleClone = cloneAndAddSegments(circle);
const rectangleClone = cloneAndAddSegments(rectangle);

const showSegments = (item) => {
    item.segments.forEach(({ point }) => new Path.Circle({
        center: point,
        radius: 5,
        fillColor: 'orange'
    }))
}

showSegments(circle);
showSegments(rectangle);
showSegments(circleClone);
showSegments(rectangleClone);

project.activeLayer.fitBounds(view.bounds.scale(0.8));
```

Comment: Hi Sasensi, thank you fro your answer